# User can't change password after key-based SSH login

Tags: ssh, password, user-management

I have a remote machine that is configured so that a number of users can access it over SSH using key-based authentication, which works great. Users also have the option to use an RDP client to connect to the machine, but to do so, they need to set a password first.

One of our users recently wanted to go the GUI route and executed `passwd` only to be asked for his current password, which was never set in the first place.

Although an admin could assign a temporary password in situations like these, I'd like to avoid the extra steps for both user and admin if at all possible. Is there some way to get this kind of arrangement to work?

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I don't think such an arrangement would work. Allowing someone to change password without knowing the current password would be a security nightmare.

Comment: Well, now that you put it that way, it does sound like it could be a problem. On the other hand, this would be a specific situation since none of the users would be able to access the machine without choosing a password beforehand. which can only be done over SSH and requires a private key. I suppose I could also give them passwordless `sudo` access as well.